# Google BigQuery python - error paginating table

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pagination, google-bigquery

I have a large table in BigQuery, which i have to go through, get all data and process it in my GAE app. Since my table is going to be about 4m rows, i decided i have to get data via pagination mechanism implemeted in code examples here > https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data

```
def async_query(query):
    client = bigquery.Client()
    query_job = client.run_async_query(str(uuid.uuid4()), query)
    query_job.use_legacy_sql = False
    query_job.use_query_cache = False
    query_job.begin()

    wait_for_job(query_job)

    query_results = query_job.results()
    page_token = None
    output_rows = []

    while True:
        rows, total_rows, page_token = query_results.fetch_data(max_results = 200, page_token = page_token)
        output_rows = output_rows + rows
        if not page_token:
            break

def wait_for_job(job):
    while True:
        job.reload()  # Refreshes the state via a GET request.
        if job.state == 'DONE':
            if job.error_result:
                raise RuntimeError(job.errors)
            return
        time.sleep(1)
```

But when i execute it i receive an error:

```
DeadlineExceededError: The overall deadline for responding to the HTTP request was exceeded.
```

When max_results parameter > table size it works fine. When max_results < table size and pagination required - i get this error.
Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates your overall request handler processing takes too long. Very likely because of the multiple `query_results.fetch_data` iterations, due to pagination.

You may want to check:

- [Dealing with DeadlineExceededErrors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors)
- [Deadline errors: 60 seconds or less in Google App Engine](http://www.shiftedup.com/2015/03/12/deadline-errors-60-seconds-or-less-in-google-app-engine)

You'll probably have to re-think your app a bit, maybe try to not get the whole result immediately and instead either:

- get just a portion of the result
- get the result on a separate request, later on, after obtaining it in the background, for example:

  - via a single task queue request (10 min instead or 60s deadline)
  - by assembling it from multiple chunks collected in separate task queue requests to really make it scalable (not sure if this actually works with bigquery, I only tried it with the datastore)